# some confusion with convex

Tags: real-analysis

let  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is  a  continuous   function.

Choose  the  correct option

$1.$ If $f$  is  convex , then $f$ is  constant

$2.$ If   is  concave and  bounded  below  , then $f$  is  constant

$3.$ If  is convex , then $f$ is uniformly continuous

$4.$ None  of these

My try :  My  friend sourav was  saying me that  option  $3$ will  be correct take  $f(x)  = e^{-x}$ I'm  also  confused  that it is true or not

Pliz help me

thanks u

Comment: Sourav is not correct, not to mention an example is not full justification for something being true, it can only be full justification for a counterexample. Can you think of a more basic example of a convex function that may not be uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What is the confusion about? Do you know whether $f(x)=e^x$ is continuous? Is it uniformly continuous? Is it convex?

Comment: I think 2) is the right option.

Comment: @IvanNeretin okss  i got little points

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy pliz  give  some hints

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments $e^x$ is convex and continuous, but not uniformly continuous and not constant. Another similar example is $f(x)=x^2$.

If $f$ is continuous, concave and bounded below, then $f$ is constant. 
Indeed suppose such an $f$ were not constant and take $a<b$ with 
$f(a)\neq f(b)$. Let $L$ be the line through points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. 
Then in the interval $[a,b]$ the graph of $f$ must be above or on the line $L$, 
whereas in intervals $(-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty)$ the graph of $f$ must be below or on the line $L$. The latter condition contradicts that $f$ is bounded below. The contradiction proves that $f$ must be constant. The condition that $f$ is continuous is redundant: Every concave function defined on an open intervals must be continuous.

Regarding $e^{-x}$ it is just like $e^x$ (their graphs are symmetric about the $y$-axis. The function $e^{-x}$ is convex, but not uniformly continuous, as 
for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have that $e^{-x+\varepsilon}-e^{-x}=e^{-x}\cdot(e^\varepsilon-1)\to\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is the good one.

**EDIT :** the other answer gives you the geometric intuition about the problem, this one is more about technical arguments and details, which are not that easy in this case since we only ask for continuity.

> $f$ is concave iff : $$ \forall (x,y), ~ t\in[0,1]~:~f((1-t)x+ty) \ge
>  (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).$$

$f$ is bounded below, it has an infimum, noted $m$.

If $m = f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$, then for all $x,y$ such that $x < x_0 <y$, we can find $t_0$ such that $x_0=(1-t_0)x+t_0y$. Then :

$$m=f(x_0) \ge (1-t_0)f(x)+t_0f(y) \ge (1-t_0)m+t_0m=m.$$

Hence : $(1-t_0)f(x)+t_0f(y)=m$. Suppose $f(x)>m$, then $(1-t_0)f(x) >(1-t_0)m$ and equality cannot happen since $f(y) \ge m$, same goes if you suppose $f(y) >m$. Then $f(x) = f(y) =m$.

So if $f$ is not constant, infimum must be reached at $\infty$. Suppose it is when $x \to \infty$. Let $x_0$ some point in $\mathbb{R}$, $y_n =n^2$ and $t_n = \frac 1 n$. then :

$$f\left(\left( 1- \frac 1 n\right)x_0+n\right)=f((1-t_n)x_0+t_ny_n) \ge (1-t_n)f(x_0)+t_nf(y_n) = \left(1- \frac 1 n \right)f(x_0)+\frac 1 n f(n^2)$$

But :

$$f\left(\left( 1- \frac 1 n\right)x_0+n\right) \to_{n\to \infty} m$$

And :

$$\left(1- \frac 1 n \right)f(x_0)+\frac 1 n f(n) \to_{n\to \infty} f(x_0)$$

Since $f(n^2)$ tends to $m$.

Finally, $m \ge f(x_0)$.

Since $m$ is the infimum, $f(x_0)=m$.